# ExtJS: Check if Component is direct descendant of Ext.TabPanel

Tags: javascript, extjs

So far EVERY ONE of my questions was already asked and answered here, to many thanks to all time machine help I already got here. :) But everything ends one day and so here is my first own question:

For error handling purposes, I'm trying to attach some generic listeners to all interesting components as they are added. This can be done with `Ext.ComponentMgr.all.on('add', function (cnt, cmp) {})`. Then I look what type of component it is, for example to add a click listener to every button.

What I now need to do is to add an activate listener to every panel which is added to a tabpanel. My problem is: I have no clue how to determine if a component is a direct descendant of a tabpanel and how to do it the right way.

I already tried this:

```
Ext.ComponentMgr.all.on('add', function (cnt, cmp) {
    if (cmp.ownerCt != undefined && cmp.ownerCt.getXType () == 'tabpanel') {
        console.log (cmp.getXType () + ' in tabpanel with id "' + cmp.getId ());
    }
});
```

The bad thing is, some Ext doc reads "Do not rely on ownerCt" and it's right: Every other of my components have an ownerCt, but NOT panels when added late to tabpanels.

I know there is Ext.Panel.findParentByType(), but this finds containers at any level above and I don't think it's the right way (-> performance).

Thanks in advance for every answer!

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the ownerCt may get poked in at any time during the construction depending on the order in which you do it. Why not create a tab panel subclass that automatically handles it for you?

Answer (score 0):

I've done some more trial and error and found a solution for myself. I think I should share it with you, maybe someone can use it one day:

When `Ext.ComponentMgr.all.on('add', function (cnt, cmp) {})` fires, ownerCt is of course empty, because the component only has been created, but not necessarily added to another component.

So I've done the following:

```
Ext.ComponentMgr.all.on('add', function (cnt, cmp) {
  cmp.addListener ('added', function (cmp) {
    var parent = cmp.findParentByType ('tabpanel');
    if (parent != undefined) {
      if (parent.items.contains (cmp)) {
        cmp.addListener ('activate', function (cmp) {
          doThings();
        });
      }
    }
  });
}
```

- When the component is added to the component manager (`new Ext.Panel()`), create a listener for `added` to the component
- When added, check if any parent is a tabpanel
- If it is, check if you component is a direct descendant of the tabpanel (= is contained in its items)
- ???
- Profit!

Comment: It's not a very good solution, since it means that you have to do these gymnastics every time a component is created. It would be much simpler and cleaner to create a tab panel subclass and handle it there directly.